# Unable to combine two dictionaries in Ansible 2.9 (works in 2.10)

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-2.x

Need to combine two config files to utilize shared variables concept for deployment. Using Ansible, merging two dictionaries imported from YML files into one:

shared.yml:

```
---
settings:
  name: "{{ name }}"
  docker_options:
    env:
      - profile={{ profile }}
```

env_specific.yml:

```
---
settings:
  image: "{{ image }}"
  tag: "{{ tag }}"
  docker_options:
    env:
      - customer={{ customer }}
    replicas: "{{ replicas }}"
```

Expecting combined settings dictionary:

```
name: "{{ name }}"
image: "{{ image }}"
tag: "{{ tag }}"
docker_options:
  env:
    - customer={{ customer }}
    - profile={{ profile }}
  replicas: "{{ replicas }}"
```

Using this approach with Ansible 2.10 and getting expected results:

```
  tasks:

    - name: include 1
      include_vars:
        file: "env_specific.yml"
      register: env_specific

    - name: include 2
      include_vars:
        file: "shared.yml:"
      register: env_shared

    - name: combine two configs
      set_fact:
        settings: "{{ env_specific | combine(env_shared, recursive=True, list_merge='append') }}"
```

Deployment server has Ansible 2.9 installed and combine expression results in error:

```
FAILED! => {"msg": "'recursive' is the only valid keyword argument"}
```

I have tried all combinations of "combine" in local environment with Ansible 2.9 but none producing expected results. This one makes the most sense to me, but it results only in one config being taken in consideration:

```
      set_fact:
        settings: "{{ env_specific | combine(env_shared, recursive=True) }}"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The option `list_merge` was indeed added to `combine` in the version 2.10. I don't think there was an equivalent to that before.

Answer (score 0):

Create custom filer. For example

```py
shell> cat filter_plugins/combine_lossless.py

def combine_lossless(x, y, flatten=False):
    d = x.copy()
    d.update(y)
    for key, value in d.items():
        if key in x and key in y:
            if flatten:
                d[key] = value + x[key]
            else:
                d[key] = [value, x[key]]
    return d

class FilterModule(object):
    ''' Ansible filters. '''

    def filters(self):
        return {
            'combine_lossless': combine_lossless,
        }
```

<sup>[[dict_filters.py](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-plugins/blob/master/filter_plugins/dict_filters/dict_filters.py#L30)]</sup>

Then `combine_lossless` *docker_options* and combine the dictionaries. For example

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    name1: my_name
    image: my_image
    tag: my_tag
    replicas: my_replicas
    profile: my_profile
    customer: my_customer
    shrd:
      settings:
        name: "{{ name1 }}"
        docker_options:
          env:
            - profile="{{ profile }}"
    spec:
      settings:
        image: "{{ image }}"
        tag: "{{ tag }}"
        docker_options:
          env:
            - customer="{{ customer }}"
          replicas: "{{ replicas }}"

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        settings: "{{ shrd.settings|
                      combine(spec.settings)|
                      combine({'docker_options': do}) }}"
      vars:
        do: "{{ shrd.settings.docker_options|
                combine_lossless(spec.settings.docker_options, flatten=true) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  settings:
    docker_options:
      env:
      - customer="my_customer"
      - profile="my_profile"
      replicas: my_replicas
    image: my_image
    name: my_name
    tag: my_tag
```